# what host object to use for javascript event handlers

Tags: java, graalvm, graaljs

I want to allow JavaScript to register events, with a syntax like

```
object.on('eventName', (event) => {
  event.something();
});
```

The `event` object provides different methods depending on what `'eventName'` is (depending on what type of event I'd like to add a handler for).

I will need to create host objects for `object` and for `event`, I'm assuming the class needed for `object` will have to look something like

```
public class Events {
  public void on(String eventName, X<FirstEvent> event) {
    // ...
  }

  public void on(String eventName, X<SecondEvent> event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If there are two types of events.

But I don't know how to get graalvm to automatically choose the correct `on` method, and I don't know what type to use for the second argument (it has to be a JavaScript anonymous function which accepts a single argument of a certain type, and must be runnable later by my Java code).

How can I store JavaScript anonymous function

```
(event) => {
  event.something();
}
```

as some kind of Java Runnable, and make sure GraalVM knows which `on` method to use depending on the value of the first string argument (because the `event` objects passed will be different for different events).

I think this may be a super complex question, I'm finding it tricky to phrase properly.

I'd like to create a way for JavaScript to register event handlers that are functions that will be called at later times with certain arguments.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you would like to have overloaded `on` methods and have GraalVM automatically pick the correct one based on the *value* of the `eventName`? Because the second argument to `on` have the type: `Consumer<Event>`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what the question is asking, but I hope this helps.

In order for this snippet to work:

```
object.on('eventName', (event) => {
  event.something();
});
```

The simplest Java class that would work for the interoperability purposes:

```
public class MyJavaClass { 
  public void on(String type, Consumer<Object> handler) {
  }
}
```

Then you can use if from JavaScript like:

```
const myJavaClassType = Java.type('MyJavaClass')
var object = new myJavaClassType();

object.on('X', (event) => { console.log(event) })
```

This would work, and the method `.on()` would run and you can store the `handler` to invoke at some later time.

In Java there's no method overloading based on the *value* of the parameters. So if you want to invoke the specific handler based on the value of the `eventName` you need to write it yourself.

Something like this perhaps:

```
public class MyJavaClass { 
  private Map<String, Consumer<Object>> handlers = new HashMap<>();

  public void fire(String type, Object event) { 
    Consumer<Object> handler = handlers.get(type);
    if(handler != null) { 
        handler.accept(event);
    }
  }

  public void on(String type, Consumer<Object> handler) {
      handlers.put(type, handler);
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not this helped him, but it helped me.  I am converting from Nashorn to graal.js for user-defined extensions to my kotlin/java program.  I was handling callbacks like this with something called ScriptObjectMirror (that is part of Nashorn) and I was trying to find the graal.js way to do it.  Your answer clued me in that I just need to go back to java.util.function.  I changed my @FunctionalInterface to a Consumer<T> and it works.  That was the only change I had to make to move from Nashorn to embedded graal.js -- Yay!  Thanks for your answer.